# Bash: substring of a constant string

Tags: string, bash

I know, that there is a way to get substring of a string variable:

```
MY_STR=abacaba
echo ${MY_STR:2:6}
```

Is there a way to get substring of a string given as literal constant? Something like:

```
echo ${"abacaba":2:6}
```

Comment: How would that be useful (I remember I wanted to be able to do this before as well, but I really don't remember the use case)?

Comment: @AdrianFrühwirth, for using in inline commands. `find . -exec bash -c "echo \"{}\" | cut -c3-" \;` for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `cut`:

```
$ echo abacaba | cut -c3-7
acaba
```

Saying `-c3-7` would get characters 3 to 7 (note that the first character is denoted by `1`).

For getting all the characters starting from the 3rd one, you could say:

```
$ echo abacaba | cut -c3-
acaba
```

You can also use `tail`:

```
$ echo abacaba | tail -c+3
acaba
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using cut you could do:

> echo "abacaba" | cut -c3-7

Answer (score 1):

There isn't but you could have alternatives like using a function:

```
function getsub {
    sub="${1:$2:$3}"
}

getsub abacaba 2 6
echo "$sub"

function printsub {
    echo "${1:$2:$3}"
}

printsub abacaba 2 6
```

Answer (score 1):

`expr` can deal with string literals.

```
expr substr STR POS LEN
```

- STR: the constant string.
- POS: the index of the first char of the substring (starting from 1).
- LEN: the length of the substring.

So in your example, it should be `expr substr 'abacaba' 3 6`